# Iterate array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript and I don't know how to iterate array of arrays in
javascript.

I have a problem where I have to find largest array from an array of array input:

> Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided
>   sub-array. For simplicity, the provided array will contain exactly 4
>   sub-arrays. Remember, you can iterate through an array with a simple
>   for loop, and access each member with array syntax arr[i]

First problem is solved by me successfully whose code I have written at the end but I am not able to solve the second input.

**Problem 1 *[SOLVED]***

- Input: `largestOfFour( [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39],[1000,1001, 857, 1]] );`
- Output: `[1000,1001,857,1]`

**Problem 2 *[NOT SOLVED]***

- Input: `largestOfFour(  [[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]), [27,5,39,1001] );`
- Output: `[27,5,39,1001]`

If still not clear watch this link and tell me thats it

http://freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-return-largest-numbers-in-arrays

My Code for the first problem. (Alter my code so that second can be solved)

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var iAmLarge = new Array();
  iAmLarge = arr[0];
  var large = iAmLarge[0];

  for(var i=0;i<iAmLarge.length;i++) {
     if(large<=iAmLarge[i] ) {
        large = iAmLarge[i];
     }     
  }
  var maxFoundAt = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ 
    var newArray=new Array();
    newArray = arr[i];
    var max = newArray[0];
    for(var j=0;j<newArray.length;j++) {
        if(max<newArray[j] ) {
        max = newArray[j];
     }     
    }
if(max>=large) {        
        large = max;
        maxFoundAt = i;     
    }
  } 
alert( arr[maxFoundAt]);
}

largestOfFour( [[4, 9, 1, 3], [13, 35, 18, 26], [32, 35, 97, 39], [1000000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: Are those problems homework or something like that?

Comment: @EnriMR It does not matter, as OP showed the proper effort into solving it by himself.

Comment: Define "Largest array". (Highest number/Highest Sum/etc)

Comment: I have to questions, for the second problem, is the output you gave the expected output or your output? Also I'm not quite sure what you mean by largest.

Comment: Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array. For simplicity, the provided array will contain exactly 4 sub-arrays.

Remember, you can iterate through an array with a simple for loop, and access each member with array syntax arr[i] .

Comment: According to that description your first answer is also wrong. the result for 1 should be `[5,27,39,1001]` - the highest number from each array

Comment: another ainput - largestOfFour( [[4, 9, 1, 3], [13, 35, 18, 26], [32, 35, 97, 39], [1000000, 1001, 857, 1]]), [9,35,97,1000000], 'arrays should match.');arrays should match.: expected [ Array(4) ] to deeply equal [ 9, 35, 97, 1000000 ]

Comment: another input largestOfFour( [[4, 9, 1, 3], [13, 35, 18, 26], [32, 35, 97, 39], [1000000, 1001, 857, 1]]), [9,35,97,1000000], 'arrays should match.'); output [ 9, 35, 97, 1000000 ]

Comment: @HarshSharma what about you define in the English language the problem instead of providing input and outputs?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia - look a few comments up. Providing lots of inputs/outputs is a bit overkill, but they already did what you asked.

Comment: i got it did you see that in second input which i have provided i am not able to access this array as it is after an arrays of array  by , [27,5,39,1001]

Answer (score 3):

For the second problem where you want to collect the largest number from each sub-array, you can do this (working snippet):

```js
function largestOfFour(master) {
    var result = [];
    // iterate through all arrays passed
    for (var i = 0; i < master.length; i++) {
        // master[i] is an array and can be just treated like any array
        result.push(Math.max.apply(Math, master[i]));
    }
    return result;
}

var r = largestOfFour(  [[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

// show result in snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(r));
```

---

To explain a bit, `Math.max.apply(Math, array)` is a trick for finding the largest value in an array.  It works like this:

`Math.max()` accepts as many arguments as you want to pass it.  For example, you can do `Math.max(1,2,3,4,5,6)` and it will return `6`.  So, if you could pass it a whole array of arguments, then it would find the max value in the whole array.

So, how do you turn an array of values into a set of arguments to a function.  Well, you can use `.apply()` to do that.  It's a method on any function in Javascript.  You can read about [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).  So, since `Math.max()` is a function, we can use `Math.max.apply()` to use an array of values as the arguments for `Math.max()`.  `.apply()` accepts two arguments itself.  The first is the `this` value that you want the function to have.  That, it turns out is not really relevant here so we pass `Math` which just gives the `.max()` function the same `this` value that it would have if we called it as `Math.max()`.  The second argument to `.apply()` is an array of values that we want to be the arguments to our function.  For that, we just pass our array.  So, we end up with:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, myArray);
```

to find the largest value in myArray.  To see how this works, let's suppose that we have:

```
var myArray = [9,8,7,1];
var highest = Math.max.apply(Math, myArray);
```

That is the same as this:

```
var highest = Math.max(9,8,7,1);
```

The `Math.max.apply(Math, myArray)` takes the array of values in `myArray` and passes them as consecutive arguments to `Math.max()` just as if we had typed them into our code manually as arguments.

And, in both cases above, `highest === 9`.

Comment: @Jamiec - That's might be an issue for the OP (they will have to decide what to use), but I'm not going to teach an inefficient way to do it.  I'm showing a good way to solve the problem.  `Math.max.apply()` is a well known trick for finding the largest value in an array because `Math.max()` accepts as many arguments as you want to pass it and it will find the max value of all of them, so you can pass it an entire array by using `.apply()`.

Comment: I tend to agree, but there are already loads of places to learn that trick. I kind of see the analogy that a high school physics student has asked about atoms and you've delved into quantum mechanics ;)

Comment: @Jamiec - put another way.  Our job is to teach good ways to solve the problem.  It is the OP's job to understand what we teach and decide what to use for their homework.

Comment: @Jamiec - there's no quantum mechanics here.  Just a simple `for` loop and a trick for finding the max value in an array.  If the OP wants to replace the `Math.max.apply()` trick with their own max finding function, that is up to them.

Comment: Added explanation of how `Math.max.apply(Math, array)` works to teach the concept of using `.apply()` and using `Math.max()` with more than two values.

Comment: @jamiec it is not a homework i am just stuck with this  how to access this in second input  which is a array after arrays of arrays  <<< ,[27,5,39,1001] >>> thats it   i have never seen this kind of input in any problem as i am new to javascript i tried my level best and you are saying its a homework

Comment: @HarshSharma if this isnt homework (or, perhaps a learning exercise - same thing) then i'm a monkey's uncle.

Comment: @Jamiec yours solution is 10000% corrrect perfect for first one but give it second one iyou not gonna get the result that's it

Comment: @Jamiec check this  http://freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-return-largest-numbers-in-arrays

Comment: @jfriend00 check this and tell me whats wrong with my problem http://freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-return-largest-numbers-in-arrays

Answer (score 2):

You have stated (in comments, and from the link provided) the problems set is

> Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array. For simplicity, the provided array will contain exactly 4 sub-arrays. Remember, you can iterate through an array with a simple for loop, and access each member with array syntax arr[i]

Which means that what you need to do is iterate each array and find the highest number *from each array* and return an array containing the highest number from each sub array. Therefore an input of:

```
 [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39],[1000,1001, 857, 1]]
```

Should yield a response of

```
[5,27,39,1001]
```

In order to achieve anything in programming you should break a complex problem down into one or more simpler problems - this often results in writing a function to perform a small unit of functionality.

Start with a simple 1-dimensional array

```
[4, 5, 1, 3]
```

And write a function to find the highest number from that array.

```
function getLargestFromArray(arr){
    // You can do this bit!
    // Its easy, just store zero in a variable, and iterate the array
    // if the current value is greater than the stored number
    // set the stored number to this value
    // when youve iterated all values return the currently stored highest number
}
```

Now, you know your original input will be an array of 4 arrays (the assignment said so!) so you can use the number 4 to iterate the input

```
var output = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    var thisArr = input[i];
    var highest = getLargestFromArray(thisArr)
    output[i] = highest; // or output.push(highest);
}
```

It's that simple!

Comment: The thing you are saying is i have already done with but what is this thing  largestOfFour(  [[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]), [27,5,39,1001] );  There is an array of arrays but how to access this [27,5,39,1001]  i am not able to access it anymore

Comment: @HarshSharma the `[27,5,39,1001]` in that example is the *expected result*! Its not another array in the input - the assignment says they array will always contain *4 sub arrays*. You're getting yourself confused.

Comment: As it happens, I have. Why?

Comment: anyway you have told me some other stuffs of javascript  and i have also figured out the problem thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

This will work for any number of subarrays, so I would change the name to `maxOfSubArrays` or something similar. It's similar to @Jamiec solution but uses the map function to apply the max function to each sub array, you don't need to cycle over the main array.

```
function largestOfFour(arrayOfArrays) {
    return arrayOfArrays.map(function (singleArray) {
        return Math.max.apply(null, singleArray);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLn3k14n/

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];
var temp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  temp.push(a[i].sort(function(a, b){return b - a;})[0]);
}
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers on here are really outdated.  Use the array map function and just grab the max from each array like so.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(m=>Math.max(...m));
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

that function can be simplified any further using arrow syntax

```
const largestOfFour=a=>a.map(m=>Math.max(...m))
```